# Is there a source of information on the Aerodynamics of Non Rotating Round Disc Wings?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

Is there any published information on the aerodynamics of Fixed round disc wings like that used on the Nemeth Parasol?

https://disciplesofflight.com/nemeth-parasol-strange-aircraft/

All I've found so far is info on rotating discs like the Frisbee or Olympic discus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

The first published results of measurements made by [O. Flachsbart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Flachsbart) of the [AVA Göttingen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodynamische_Versuchsanstalt) on a flat disk can be found in the collection [Ergebnisse IV](https://www.univerlag.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/3/isbn-978-3-941875-42-5/Prandtl_4.pdf) (PDF!). He reported on a hysteresis in the angle of attack range between 39° and 42°, where the wing is either stalled or not, depending from which side this angle of attack range is approached.

[image: Lift and pitching moment coefficients of a flat disk]

<sub>Lift and pitching moment coefficients of a flat disk, page 97 of Ergebnisse IV</sub>

When [C. H. Zimmerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Zimmerman) tested disk-shaped wings with an [Clark Y airfoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark_Y) section in the early 1930s in the NACA 7 x 10 ft wind tunnel, he called them circular airfoils. The results of this testing can be found in [NACA Technical Note 539](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1935/naca-tn-539.pdf) (PDF!) from August 1935.

[image: Figures 10 and 11 from the last page of NACA TN 539]
<sub>Figures 10 and 11 from the last page of NACA TN 539</sub>

[Sighard Hörner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sighard_F._Hoerner) collected the little data available on circular wings in his book [Fluid Dynamic Drag](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx0MqOfev7dnTnB0eFRIN2JQb0k/edit?pli=1) (page 17-8) and concluded:

> Disregarding any dreams of "flying saucers", the athletic implement
>   called discus seems to be the only practical application of a circular
>   planform.

However, Zimmerman went on to inspire the [Vought V-173](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_V-173), the "flying pancake" of 1942, from which the [Vought XF5U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_XF5U) was developed.

[image: Vought V-173 in flight]
<sub>Vought V-173 in flight (picture [source](http://blog.lotnicze-bilety.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Vought-V-173.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Note: Sighard Horner's comments and information about the discus is on page 17-8 of "Fluid Dynamic LIFT"

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/erbuc/files/4099_22ac3a91-02b3-4e33-9e95-4caf350b518d.pdf

Many thanks for the gold mine of information in both "Fluid Dynamic Drag" and "Fluid Dynamic LIFT". These two sources have saved me a huge amount of time searching the internet for answers to specific questions.